# Automatic expiration of user-created temp directories

Tags: windows, file-management, windows-10

Is there software where I can set specific directories as "temporary" and automatically delete files in there as the size of that folder grows or the time passes.

Kind of like clipboard for files.

Comment: You could use the Windows Tack Scheduler (or CcCleaner) to empty the directory periodically.

Comment: I use Screenshot Captor as my screenshot utility.  One specifies a directory from which files are automatically deleted as they reach the age of one month.  This might enable you to make a kluge; or you could write to the developer for advice.